# Devise super user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use devise for signup, and each user belongs to a location. I want to create a super user who will have access to all locations regardless of how many are created.

Currently the location param is location_id = some integer

Any ideas on how to assign a location_id to the super user that equals all locations?

I should also add that the purpose of this is to give my iOS app the ability to authenticate and view all api data.

I am now trying to define location_id = nil to return location.all

```
if current_user.location = nil
    @locations = Location.all
  else
    @locations = current_user.location
  end
```

but I still need to define nil because I get the following error when loggin in with a user that has a location_id = nil

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"locations", :id=>nil}

Comment: Going to locations#show should only ever give a single location. Go to locations#index, instead: `/locations` rather than `/locations/nil`

Comment: Thanks Tim. Going to locations#index won't work because the index page is looking for current_user.locations. I'm trying to figure out how to define if @location = nil current_user.locations = Location.all

Comment: It's going to `current_user.locations` because you told it to go to `current_user.locations`. There's nothing stopping you from having it go to `Location.all` if the `current_user.location = nil`. Forcing #show to return a list is the wrong thing to do, and it'll only create a lot of headaches for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the finer details of what you're doing but, you could add a `super_user` boolean field to your model, and in the controller simply use something like this:

```
if current_user.super_user
  @locations = Location.all
else
  @locations = current_user.location
end
```

Alternately, you could use a location_id of nil to represent "all", and instead use `if current_user.location` instead of `if current_user.super_user`, if that works better for your needs.

Comment: Thanks this has me on the right track. I think using a location_id of nil to represent "all" will work best, but wondering how to define that?